# Rotating an image in feh through the command line without editing the file

Tags: linux, image, debian, feh

I'm using feh to open an image, but I need the image to be rotated only in the feh window. I can't find the command for that, but since it does allow you to rotate the image by pressing the </> keys, there must be a command that does the same thing, right? What is that command, or how can I find out what the command is?

My code right now:

`feh --borderless --auto-zoom --image-bg "#555555" --geometry $geometry "$IMAGESDIRECTORY/$img"`

I tried --auto-rotate but that's deprecated and I don't want to be automatic anyway, I want to determine myself when to rotate the image.
I also tried -rotate 90deg, --rotate 90deg, -rotate 90, -rotate but none of them worked.
--rotate returns "feh: unrecognized option '--rotate'"

Comment: Maybe copy the image to `/tmp` before opening, then you can rotate it without affecting the original.